# Avoiding NULL return value with GREATEST function

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I avoid a `null` return value when invoking the `greatest` function with a `null` parameter. Example:

```
select greatest(1,null,2) from dual
```

The above returns `null`, but I want `2`.

I don't want to use `nvl` and also not something like:

```
coalesce(greatest(term1,term2,term3), greatest(term1,term2), term1).
```

Is there is any other way of avoiding the `null` return value?

Comment: Given your restrictions, I don't think it's possible.  That's just the way `greatest` works.

Comment: do it without oracle or mysql and do it without passing null to the greatest function.

Comment: @JayKumarR - please supply an answer with an example of what you're trying to communicate. Thanks.

Comment: Why avoid `NVL` or `COALESCE`?  They'll give you cleaner code than using a CTE with `MAX` and `UNION ALL`.

Comment: What is wrong with NVL? Is that a constraint in a homework assignment? It can't be a business requirement (I don't think).

Comment: Without a clear explanation of *why* the simple methods are not good enough this is a trivia question not likely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION greatest_ignore_null(
  vals SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  output NUMBER := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. vals.COUNT LOOP
    IF vals(i) IS NOT NULL AND ( output IS NULL OR vals(i) > output ) THEN
      output := vals(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN output;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT greatest_ignore_null(
         SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, NULL, 3, NULL, 2 )
       ) AS largest
FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
LARGEST
-------
      3
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a SELECT query with a common table expression to put the values into something resembling a table, and then use the SQL `MAX` function in a manner similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
  n1    NUMBER := 1;
  n2    NUMBER := NULL;
  n3    NUMBER := 3;
  nMin  NUMBER := -99999999999999999999999999999999999999e125;
  nMax  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  WITH CTE AS (SELECT n1 AS N FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT n2 AS N FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT n3 AS N FROM DUAL)
  SELECT MAX(COALESCE(n, nMin))
    INTO nMax
    FROM CTE;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nMax=' || nMax);
END;
```

The above uses `COALESCE`, which is the ANSI equivalent of NVL. If you don't want to use either `NVL` or `COALESCE` you can use a `CASE`-expression instead:

```
  WITH CTE AS (SELECT n1 AS N FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT n2 AS N FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT n3 AS N FROM DUAL)
  SELECT MAX(CASE
               WHEN N IS NULL THEN nMin
               ELSE N
             END)
    INTO nMax
    FROM CTE;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: How would this work on a table with 10,000 rows? (Of course it can be done, but it will be even more work.) Also, why is PL/SQL needed here?

Answer (score 1):

If you use an aggregate function like `MAX`, `NULL` values will be be excluded. But then your data needs to come in as rows.

```
WITH mylist AS (
  SELECT NULL AS id FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT MAX(id)
  FROM mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, No `NVL` `VALUE` or `COALESCE`

```
CASE
 WHEN term1 IS NULL AND term2 IS NOT NULL AND term3 IS NOT NULL
 THEN GREATEST(term2,term3)

 WHEN term1 IS NOT NULL AND term2 IS NULL AND term3 IS NOT NULL
 THEN GREATEST(term1,term3)

 WHEN term1 IS NOT NULL AND term2 IS NOT NULL AND term3 IS NULL
 THEN GREATEST(term1,term2)

 WHEN term1 IS NOT NULL AND term2 IS NULL AND term3 IS NULL
 THEN term1

 WHEN term1 IS NULL AND term2 IS NOT NULL AND term3 IS NULL
 THEN term2

 WHEN term1 IS NULL AND term2 IS NULL AND term3 IS NOT NULL
 THEN term3

 ELSE GREATEST(term1,term2,term3)
END
```

But you really should `COALESCE` each term with a suitably low value.

```
DECLARE MIN_INT CONSTANT := -2147483648;
GREATEST(COALESCE(term1,MIN_INT),COALESCE(term2,MIN_INT),COALESCE(term3,MIN_INT))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not "coalesce" but rater NVL. If you knew beforehand that the other two values are, for example, positive numbers, then you could do something like `greatest(1, NVL(null, -1), 2)` - or, more likely, if you have three numeric columns, any one of which could be NULL, and you knew all values must be positive numbers, you could do something like `greatest(NVL(col1, -1), NVL(col2, -1), NVL(col3, -1))` - and then, if the result is -1, you would know all three values were NULL.

However, if you allow NULL that probably means you may, sometimes, have values that are not known. Is it not possible that the greatest among your values is in fact one of these unknown values? (That is, isn't NULL the correct answer for `greatest()` in that case?)

ADDED: You can always avoid `coalesce` and `NVL`, for example instead of `NVL(col1, -1)` you can write `case when col1 is null then -1 else col1 end` - but WHY???

Comment: Please explain why `COALESCE` would not work. Thanks.

Comment: It would not work in the way the OP meant it, did you read what he wrote? NVL itself IS a coalesce, but that's beside the point. It can't be `coalesce(greatest(col1, col2, col3), greatest(col1, col2), col1)` - what if `col1` is null but `col2` and `col3` are not? And if you throw in more arguments to coalesce, in what order do you write them? (Hint: whatever order you put them in, it will not be the correct answer to "greatest with ignore nulls".)

Answer (score 0):

As per your example try this one :

select greatest(1,nvl(null,0),2) from dual;