# How to get min and max from 7 columns in Hive Hue excluding zeros

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hue

I have a table which has 9 columns. Below is the structure of it

[image: Raw Table Structure]

I need the min and max of these columns for a row excluding zeros. Below is the required table structure

[image: Output Required]

If you see the columns min and max, min is minimum of 7 cols (col1 to col7) in a particular row excluding zero and max is the maximum of the 7 cols (col1 to col7) for that row.

Please help me to accomplish this in hive (hue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least` and `greatest` to get the min and max, and use `when` to remove `0`.

```
select *,
    least(
        case when col1 != 0 then col1 else 99999999 end,
        case when col2 != 0 then col2 else 99999999 end,
        case when col3 != 0 then col3 else 99999999 end,
        case when col4 != 0 then col4 else 99999999 end,
        case when col5 != 0 then col5 else 99999999 end,
        case when col6 != 0 then col6 else 99999999 end,
        case when col7 != 0 then col7 else 99999999 end,
    ) as `Min`
    greatest(
        case when col1 != 0 then col1 else -99999999 end,
        case when col2 != 0 then col2 else -99999999 end,
        case when col3 != 0 then col3 else -99999999 end,
        case when col4 != 0 then col4 else -99999999 end,
        case when col5 != 0 then col5 else -99999999 end,
        case when col6 != 0 then col6 else -99999999 end,
        case when col7 != 0 then col7 else -99999999 end
    ) as `Max`
from mytable
```

Comment: This will not work because least function is Fixed to return NULL when one or more arguments are NULL. For example, if a column has zero as value then case statement will give NULL as output which makes the least or greatest function result as NULL. But NULL is not the desired output.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that Hive has this behaviour. How about adding `else 99999999` for `least` and `else -99999999` for `greatest`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530880/avoiding-null-return-value-with-greatest-function for more examples

Comment: There is no point in giving 99999999 because if the sample values from col1 to col7 are 0,25,2,587,0,1,45 we need the result to be 1 not 99999999.

Comment: @Pushpakkvh not sure if you understood my comment, but could you have a look at the edited answer please?

Comment: I got it but what will happen in the extreme case (if there are numbers greater than 99999999)?

Comment: @KVHP then you can use an even larger number for this purpose. For an integer type column, the largest possible number is 2147483647.

Comment: Do we have any other way, apart from assigning a bigger number manually and doing it. Another thing is, do we have any other solution that will improve the efficiency?

Comment: That's the only way that I can think of... Using the biggest possible number allowed by the datatype of that column should be a reliable and efficient way, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530880/avoiding-null-return-value-with-greatest-function

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit `case` expression:

```
select (case when col1 <> 0 and col1 >= col2 and col1 >= col3 and col1 > =col4 and col1 >= col5 and col1 >= col6 and col1 >= col7
             then col1
             . . .
        end)
```

This is a lot of typing.  It probably suggests that your data is stored incorrectly -- you should have separate rows for each column.  You can mimic this by expanding the data and reaggrating:

```
select name, state, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7,
       min(case when col1 <> 0 then col1 end) as min_value,
       max(case when col1 <> 0 then col1 end) as max_value,
from ((select t.*, col1 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col2 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col3 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col4 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col5 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col6 as col from t) union all
      (select t.*, col7 as col from t)
     ) x
group by name, state, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7;
```

Comment: This might work but this will increase the process time very much as we are considering the same columns and doing union.